# What datatype should I use for a small int values in protobuffer?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I looked at [scalar value types](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto) and it seems there's no option to store small int values (practically I need integer values 1 through 10).

Is there any option other than creating a enum with 10 possible values for this?

Comment: `bytes`? It maps to a `ByteString` so you'd need to deserialise it yourself. If it's *definitely* only 1 to 10, and any other value should be invalid, that does sound like a valid use-case for an enum.

Comment: @Michael `bytes` would be a bad choice - that will always be more expensive to encode

Answer (score 1):

You are right in that there is no specific support for a smaller primitive; that's because the schema syntax needs to support a wide range of implementations on different platforms and languages, so the types are intentionally left to a subset that will be available for most systems.

Enumerations (`enum` in .proto) are treated as `int32` values, using "varint" encoding. There's no advantage between using `int32` vs declaring an `enum` with values `Zero`, `One`, etc. So you might as well just use `int32`. As long as you only use low values, it will automatically *encode* very efficiently, simply because of how "varint" encoding works - anything in the range 0-127 will take a single byte to encode on the wire (plus the field header, which is usually another single byte for simple values).